# Kotlin DialogFragment() Inflater and access to dialog elements

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I created dialogFragment:

```
package com.intorry.intorry11
...
   
class ProductDialog : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var increaseBTN : Button
    private lateinit var decreaseBTN : Button

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(
            com.intorry.intorry11.R.layout.fragment_product_dialog,//?????
            container
        )
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        increaseBTN=view.findViewById(R.id.increase)//it doesn't work  ?????
        decreaseBTN=view.findViewById(com.intorry.intorry11.R.id.decrease)
```

Could someone explain why my code (inflater and views) doesn't work without path "com.intorry.intorry11". The normal fragments works only the problem is in dialogFragment.

Comment: Because you have imported `R class` from other library. Make sure that you have imported `import com.intorry.intorry11.R`

Comment: Thank you Savathna i had import android.R which I removed